# SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context) returns null on postback from IE browser from provider hosted app

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, spcontext

I have a provider hosted app hosted on Azure and installed in SharePoint Online (Office 365). It works fine on Google Chrome browser but fails to get SharePoint context on post back using `SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context)` on IE browser i.e first time while loading page it works well but fails on postbacks.

Details are:

1. `SharePointContextProvider.Current.GetSharePointContext(Context)` returns null in IE browser on postbacks
2. I am using update panel and button which I am using for postback is in that panel.

Am I missing something here? Any help on this will be helpful?